Best way to use pipenv to downgrade from prerelease version to latest stable?
I have been testing prerelease packages with pipenv install --pre with my Pipfile simply specifying versions = "*". Is there a better way to rollback the changes to the latest stable version, other than doing a pipenv uninstall followed by pipenv install (after removing the allow_prereleases = true setting in my Pipfile)?
